# How to allocate a char array with malloc()?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a problem trying to fill this array. Could someone explain what's going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct T
{
  char TpCode[4];

}T;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  T *tp;
  tp->TpCode =(char *)malloc(4* sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: Does this compile? If not, what does the compiler say?

Comment: Do you have a problem _filling_ the array, or _allocating_ it? Because to me it seems that you have a problem _defining_ it.

Comment: As an aside, the typedef isn't really necessary (although it is common). Try to code without it; the type declaration becomes simpler. The type name of a struct in C is simply "struct T" (instead of just "T"). Decalring tp would become `struct T *tp;`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code sample, you don't want to allocate space for the array per se, you want to allocate space to hold a `struct T` instead. This is what you should be doing:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  T *tp;
  tp = malloc(sizeof(*tp));
}
```

Since the array is part of `struct T`, allocating space for the structure implicitly allocates space for the array inside the structure.

Answer (score 0):

For array you should not use `malloc`.

```
char TpCode[4];
```

Should be used without using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

This is *undefined behaviour*

1. `TpCode` is allocated for you when an instance of T is created. This is because `TpCode` - as a fixed length array - is part of the actual structure.
2. You need to create the instance of `T` **before** using it. Writing `T tp` would be sufficient. Or, `T *tp = malloc(sizeof(T));`. My dropping the cast on the right hand side of `=` is deliberate.